# Coletar valor de um dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário

Estou em um projeto onde dentro do dicionario a key é um nome de pessoa e o valor dela é lista. A lista tem valores preenchidos como mostra o exemplo: Ana:(3,5) - "Ana" é a key do dicio e "3,5" é valor da lista criada e atribuida no dicio. Eu quero coletar esse valor "3,5", ja tentei utilizar get porém ele me retorna "None"
Código:
`nota2 = aluno.get("{}".format(aluno))`
Nesse caso, a variável "nota2" deveria ter o valor 3,5. O valor da lista sempre vai variar. Espero ter sido claro o suficiente, obrigado!

Comment: Cara você está passando uma tupla como valor de "Ana", tente {"Ana":3.5}